# How to compress HTML content with Axum / Tower?

Tags: rust, aws-lambda, rust-axum

I am trying to create a very simple API with Axum 0.7 and lambda_http 0.9

```ini
[package]
name = "api"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
axum = "0.7"
chrono = { version = "0.4" }
cookie = { version = "0.18" }
lambda_http = { version = "0.9" }
serde = "1.0"
serde_json = "1.0"
askama = { version = "0.12.1" }
tokio = { version = "1.35", features = ["macros"] }
tower-http = { version = "0.5", features = ["compression-full", "cors"] }
tracing = { version = "0.1", features = ["log"] }
tracing-subscriber = { version = "0.3", default-features = false, features = [
    "fmt",
] }
```

```rust
use axum::{
    http::{
        header::{ACCEPT, ACCEPT_ENCODING, AUTHORIZATION},
        Method,
    },
    routing::{get, post},
    Router,
};
use lambda_http::{run, Error};
use tower_http::{compression::CompressionLayer, cors::CorsLayer};


pub async fn get_index(request: Request) -> (StatusCode, Html<String>) {
    info!("-> {}", request.uri());
    info!("<- get_index");
    (StatusCode::OK, Html("<h1>/</h1>".to_string()))
}


#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let comression_layer: CompressionLayer = CompressionLayer::new()
        .br(true)
        .deflate(true)
        .gzip(true)
        .zstd(true);

    let app: Router = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(get_index))
        .layer(comression_layer)
        .fallback(not_found);
```

When I test the service locally (using cargo lambda) I get the following:

```
❯ curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br" -i http://127.0.0.1:9000/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 10
access-control-allow-credentials: true
vary: origin
vary: access-control-request-method
vary: access-control-request-headers
date: Sun, 24 Dec 2023 21:17:29 GMT

<h1>/</h1>⏎
```

Am I missing something trivial here or the API should return compressed content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked at the docs for [`CompressionLayer`](https://docs.rs/tower-http/latest/tower_http/compression/struct.CompressionLayer.html) -> [`CompressionLayer::compress_when`](https://docs.rs/tower-http/latest/tower_http/compression/struct.CompressionLayer.html#method.compress_when) -> [`Compression::compress_when`](https://docs.rs/tower-http/latest/tower_http/compression/struct.Compression.html#method.compress_when) -> [`DefaultPredicate`](https://docs.rs/tower-http/latest/tower_http/compression/struct.DefaultPredicate.html):

> This will compress responses unless:
>
> - ...
> - The response is less than 32 bytes.

Yours appears to be 11 bytes. You can override this to test if it's working by using a [closure or function](https://docs.rs/tower-http/latest/tower_http/compression/trait.Predicate.html#impl-Predicate-for-F) as the predicate, which should look something like this:

```rust
let comression_layer: CompressionLayer = CompressionLayer::new()
    .br(true)
    .deflate(true)
    .gzip(true)
    .zstd(true)
    .compress_when(|_, _, _, _| true);
```

Or you can just send a larger response.

---

On the [HTTP side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding), the server is allowed to use the `identity` encoding (no compression) as long as it hasn't been explicitly forbidden. So you could try this curl command to require compression:

```
curl -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, identity;q=0" -i http://127.0.0.1:9000/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have completely missed that.